# Assign additional namespace to project/library when compiling?

Tags: c++, namespaces, collision, code-organization

I have been given two versions of a C++-project that have pretty far diverged. Version 1 is very cleanly written and structured, version 2 is pretty far advanced in terms of capabilities but not very well organized and actually a black box.
My task would be to migrate the capabilities of version 2 into version 1.

I thought, it might be a good way to use version 2 as a black box in version 1 and then replace parts of version 2 by cleaner code while always checking that results don't change.

The problem is that I have massive namespace collision when trying to include version 2 into version 1. To avoid this, I would like to assign an individual namespace to both versions. Does anyone know, how to do this on a compiler level?

More general, has anyone experience with such problem and can give a best-practice advice? Would be very thankful!

Thanks in advance!

Comment: It really depends on the project structure, but I've found myself in similar situations and what I ended doing is wrapping everything from the more advanced (feature-wise) project in a custom namespace through sheer text substitution. At some point later I managed to even fully merge both projects and removed the namespace I had introduced.